# App doesn't work after AdMob Pro code, but works great when same code run through Android Studio to same phone via USB Debugger

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

App doesn't work after AdMob Pro code, stays stuck on some kind of a gray splash screen, but works great when same code run through Android Studio to same phone via USB (Ads show and everything, except first few seconds it seems like the splash screen is all fuzzy gray). Here's my first few lines of catlog. I'm not sure what else to include, please tell me I will right away

```
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello E/Zygote: v2
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N910V_5.1.1_0043
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10253
02-09 03:11:34.317 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-09 03:11:34.347 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-09 03:11:34.347 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-09 03:11:34.387 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello W/ActivityThread: Application com.yourname.hello can be debugged on port 8100...
02-09 03:11:34.417 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
02-09 03:11:34.437 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 47.0.2526.100 (code 252610000)
02-09 03:11:34.447 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 3427-3428)
02-09 03:11:34.447 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "47.0.2526.100", actual native library version number "47.0.2526.100"
02-09 03:11:34.457 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {2d408e55}
02-09 03:11:34.457 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "47.0.2526.100", actual native library version number "47.0.2526.100"
02-09 03:11:34.467 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(122)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-09 03:11:34.477 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
02-09 03:11:34.477 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
02-09 03:11:34.507 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/Adreno: EGLInit: QTI Build: 07/18/15, 588fe7e, I15bf295f1a
02-09 03:11:34.547 8936-9001/com.yourname.hello W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
02-09 03:11:34.557 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
02-09 03:11:34.557 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
02-09 03:11:34.597 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
02-09 03:11:34.597 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
02-09 03:11:34.617 8936-8936/com.yourname.hello D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:27] Constructor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="2.11.1" />
```

into my config.xml file